# Printing php elements inside html tags

Tags: php, html, sql, database, twitter-bootstrap

**Situation:** I'm trying to display few values from database through php variables.I'm using bootstrap and XAMPP as the server.What i'm trying to do is,get the current date and check it with the the event date which i get from database.If they both equals display the date inside that red ball.I'm trying to get it like [Mozilla Event Calendar](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/) in their web site

*for ex- I changed event date to today's date(2015-12-22) inside the phpmyadmin,yes,they both are equal,so it has to display date inside that red ball.It works for my testing place,but not inside the red ball.*

**Problem :** The problem is it just not show anything.What should i have to do to display that php elements ,within html tags?
[image]

**What I tried :(inside the redball)**

```
<div class="row LatestEventCircle">
  <div class="row container-fluid center-block text-center MainEventDate">
    <h2 class="center-block MainEventDate">
      <?php echo"$rows[$eventdate]"; ?><br>
      EVENT
    </h2>
  </div>
  <!--HERE IS THE PLACE-->
  <div class="row"></div>             
</div>
```

**This is the php script which handles database part and that testing code:**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("yaya");    
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT eventname,eventtime,eventplace,eventdate FROM event");

$eventdate='eventdate';
$eventplace ='eventplace';
$eventname ='eventname';
$eventtime='eventtime';

$datenow=date('Y-m-d');

if($sql==False) {
    die(mysql_error());
} 

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    if($datenow==$rows["eventdate"]) {
        echo "Next Event is";
        echo 'Event: ' .$rows[$eventname]. '<br/>' .'Place: ' .$rows[$eventplace].'<br/>' .'Time: '.$rows[$eventtime]. '<br/>'.'Date: '.$rows[$eventdate];
    }

    else {
        echo "No Events today"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why -1 what's wrong with the question?

Comment: actually it should be `echo "{$rows['eventdate']}"` <-- note the braces and no $ for `eventdate` and the quotes. you may not need another variable `$eventdate='eventdate';`

Comment: @bansi echo "{$rows['eventdate']}" does not work, i tried but it didn't work for me :/ result is same as before

Comment: where and how are you generating the html?

Comment: what do you mean?that <?php ?> code is inside a div tag

Comment: just wondering if it is shown on top left why not in next place

Comment: @bansi my idea was to get the desired part of output through html,if it is all printed in <?php ?> , like i showed in "This is the php script which handles database part and that testing code:" ,it works fine.But what i want is to get one part(date) of the output inside to a different html tag

Comment: I think i am getting the picture. You cannot execute PHP code from html. HTML is client side and PHP runs at server. You can fetch the result of some PHP script from server though. Try using AJAX call if you don't need to refresh. Or you may have to put the HTML in your PHP script. (I may be wrong on assuming what you are trying to do)

Comment: @bansi yeah, it seems this scope is wide, i just tried everything from SO but couldn't find the answer.If it is possible in ajax, i have to learn it now :D and  i'm trying to get it like mozilla event calendar in their web site https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before your while loop define a variable $nextEventDate, then in your loop assign what you need to this variable;

```
$nextEventDate = '';
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  if($datenow==$rows["eventdate"]) {
    $nextEventDate = $rows[$eventdate];
    echo "Next Event is";
    echo 'Event: ' .$rows[$eventname]. '<br/>' .'Place: ' .$rows[$eventplace].'<br/>' .'Time: '.$rows[$eventtime]. '<br/>'.'Date: '.$rows[$eventdate];
  } else {        
    $nextEventDate = 'No Events';
    echo "No Events today"; 
  }
}
```

Then use the $nextEventDate variable in your html (inside the redball).

```
<h2 class="center-block MainEventDate">
  <?php echo $nextEventDate ; ?><br />
  EVENT
</h2>
```

Hope this sorts it ;)

Also, I am not sure why you are selecting all the data rows from your database table and then using php to find the one with todays date. 
You should use the database query to just select today's event;

```
$todaysEventSql=mysql_query("SELECT eventname,eventtime,eventplace,eventdate FROM event WHERE DATE(eventdate) = DATE(NOW()) ");
```

Also you are using mysql_* function with are deprecated, replace with up to date equivalents;

[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php echo $rows["eventdate"]; ?>
```

Should work.

Aside from that, consider putting the key names straight away like this instead of putting them into variables and using the variables. It's redundant and adds a certain level of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is just try this...

```
 if($datenow==$rows["eventdate"])
    { 
$result = $rows[$eventname];
return result;
}


<h2><?php echo $result; ?><br>EVENT</h2>
```

remember to include the php file in the html page

Comment: This gives me this error "Notice: Use of undefined constant result - assumed 'result' in C:\xampp\htdocs\FinalFinal\index.php on line xxx"

Comment: you ar seeing undefined constant because array in $result should be within the quote  'code' $result = $rows['eventname'];

Answer (score 1):

```
echo"$rows[$eventdate]";
```

could you change to

```
echo $rows[$eventdate];
```

or

```
echo "{$rows[$eventdate]}";
```

Comment: So I think let change to hard-code
<!--
echo "{$rows['eventname'}";
-->
I think it should work.
If not, it's null variable :D

Comment: it's not null that's why i tried it in upper left corner,and it worked

Comment: I did try to test syntax:
<!--


<?php

 $test = array(
  'name' => "My name",
  'age' => 22
  );
 $key = 'name';
 echo "{$test[$key]}";
?>
-->
So the error should come from variable. 
let try to:
var_dump($rows[$eventdate]);

Answer (score 1):

or just echo this remove those return result and result variable

```
echo '<div class="row LatestEventCircle"><div class="row container-fluid center-block text-center MainEventDate">'.
        '<h2 class="center-block MainEventDate">'.$rows[$eventdate].' <br></h2></div>'.$rows[$eventname].'<div class="row"></div>
</div>';
```